# Null when combining rxjs observerables when source is empty

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

really losing my mind here.

If I have an array of state streams, I can get the state data in an array corresponding to the streams. But if I flatMap from an array with n state streams to an array with zero state streams (empty array), combineAll will not emit anything.

```
const obs1 = this.collectActiveOrders(id);
const obs2 = this.collectCompleteOrders(id);

const combined = Observable
    .combineLatest(
      obs1,
      obs2
    );

const merged = combined.flatMap(contacts => {
      return Observable.of(
        contacts.reduce((destination: any, item) => {
          return destination.concat(item);
        }, [])
      )
    });

return merged;
```

Returns null if either obs1 or obs 2 are empty :'(

Any advice would be sensational.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lcd5cn?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts
TEST ENVIRONMENT

Comment: What is the type of the signals in `obs1` and `obs2`?

Comment: @JonStødle: they are observable arrays

Comment: So they're observables of array of observable, e.g. `Observable<[Observable<T>]>`?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do? The flatMap + `Observable.of` as shown are redundant as they are equivalent to `map`, which makes me suspect what you want is different from what you have written.